# Unmarshalling an element with attributes using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm able to successfully marshall an object to XML, and vice versa except for 2 elements with attributes. any hits what i'm missing. i get null for both attributes (Role)

The unmarschel Code

```
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                .newInstance(UserListWrapper.class);
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();

        // Reading XML from the file and unmarshalling.
        UserListWrapper wrapper = (UserListWrapper) um.unmarshal(file);

        userData.clear();
        userData.addAll(wrapper.getUsers());
```

This the XML File

```
<Users>
<User Action="Insert" Id="test.user" Language="de">
    <Birthday>2000-01-01</Birthday>
    <City>ads</City>
    <Firstname>test</Firstname>
    <Gender>f</Gender>
    <Role Action="Assign" Id="wqeqw" Type="Global">wqeqw</Role>
    <Lastname>user</Lastname>
    <Role Action="Assign" Id="qweqwe" Type="Local">qweqwe</Role>
    <Login>sfrohwein</Login>
    <Matriculation>ads</Matriculation>
    <PostalCode>0</PostalCode>
    <Street>asd</Street>
</User><Users>
```

The Class Role

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Role")
public class Role {

private String id;
private String type;
private String action;

public Role() {
    this(null,null);
}

public Role(String type) {
    setType(type);
}

public Role(String id, String type) {
    setId(id);
    setType(type);
    setAction("Assign");
}

/**
 * @return the id
 */
@XmlAttribute(name="Id")
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * @param id the id to set
 */
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * @return the type
 */
@XmlAttribute(name="Type")
public String getType() {
    return type;
}

/**
 * @param type the type to set
 */
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

/**
 * @return the action
 */
@XmlAttribute(name="Action")
public String getAction() {
    return action;
}

/**
 * @param action the action to set
 */
public void setAction(String action) {
    this.action = action;
}

/**
 * @return the value
 */
@XmlValue
public String getValue() {
    return this.id;
}
```

The Class User

```
public class User {

private final Role globalRole;
private final Role localRole;
private final StringProperty login;
private final StringProperty firstName;
private final StringProperty lastName;
private final StringProperty matriculation;
private final StringProperty gender;
private final StringProperty street;
private final IntegerProperty postalCode;
private final StringProperty city;
private final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> birthday;

/**
 * Default constructor.
 */
public User() {
    this(null, null);
}

/**
 * Constructor with some initial data.
 * 
 * @param firstName
 * @param lastName
 */
public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
    this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);

    // Some initial dummy data, just for convenient testing.
    this.globalRole = new Role("Global");
    this.localRole = new Role("Local");
    this.gender = new SimpleStringProperty("f");
    this.login = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    this.matriculation = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    this.street = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    this.postalCode = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    this.city = new SimpleStringProperty("");
    this.birthday = new SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>(LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 1));
}

@XmlElement(name = "Login")
public String getLogin() {
    return login.get();
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login.set(login);
}

public StringProperty LoginProperty() {
    return login;
}

@XmlElement(name = "Matriculation")
public String getMatriculation() {
    return  matriculation.get();
}

public void setMatriculation(String matriculation) {
    this.matriculation.set(matriculation);
}

public StringProperty MatriculationProperty() {
    return matriculation;
}

@XmlElement(name = "Firstname")
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName.get();
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName.set(firstName);
}

public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
    return firstName;
}

@XmlElement(name = "Lastname")
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName.get();
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName.set(lastName);
}

public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
    return lastName;
}

@XmlElement(name = "Street")
public String getStreet() {
    return street.get();
}

public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street.set(street);
}

public StringProperty streetProperty() {
    return street;
}

@XmlElement(name = "PostalCode")
public int getPostalCode() {
    return postalCode.get();
}

public void setPostalCode(int postalCode) {
    this.postalCode.set(postalCode);
}

public IntegerProperty postalCodeProperty() {
    return postalCode;
}

@XmlElement(name = "City")
public String getCity() {
    return city.get();
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city.set(city);
}

public StringProperty cityProperty() {
    return city;
}

@XmlElement(name = "Birthday")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateAdapter.class)
public LocalDate getBirthday() {
    return birthday.get();
}

public void setBirthday(LocalDate birthday) {
    this.birthday.set(birthday);
}

public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> birthdayProperty() {
    return birthday;
}

@XmlElement(name = "Gender")
public String getGender() {
    return gender.get();
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender.set(gender);
}

public StringProperty GenderProperty() {
    return gender;
}

@XmlElement(name = "Role")
public Role getGlobalRole() {
    return globalRole;
}

public void setGlobalRole(String globalRole) {
    this.globalRole.setId(globalRole);
}

@XmlElement(name = "Role")
public Role getLocalRole() {
    return localRole;
}

public void setLocalRole(String localRole) {
    this.localRole.setId(localRole);
}
```

Class UserListWrapper

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Users")
public class UserListWrapper {

private List<User> users;

@XmlElement(name = "User")
public List<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}
}
```

Comment: What is the source code of whatever class you use to map the "User" element?

Comment: I added the missing classes.

Comment: Your Role setter methods are not true setter methods, and your Role fields are marked `final`, preventing you from giving your class a true setter method for this field. Why? Why not get rid of the final modifier, and give the User class true setter methods for the Role fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Role setter methods are not true setter methods, and your Role fields are marked `final`, preventing you from giving your class a true setter method for this field.

I suggest that you get rid of the final modifier, and give the User class true setter methods for the Role fields.

Comment: I changed the methods to true setter methods, it did work! but funnily only for one Role, i get back the "Global Role", but for the "Local Role" i get a null, i wonder if the @XmlElement(name = "Role") for both roles has any negative effect

Comment: i did a test and changed @XmlElement(name = "Role1") for Global Role and @XmlElement(name = "Role2") for Local Role, it worked perfectly. is there any way to keep @XmlElement(name = "Role") for both roles and still get it working ...